# CSS adjustment for timepicker ui bootstrap angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

i was trying to adjust the CSS for this timepicker. whats happens is that the arrows don't come exactly on top of the text boxes of hours and minutes respectively.

what i want is to hold them together no matter if its for mobile screen or for medium screens or desktop screens (responsive).

here is my html code:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="timer" >
<div class="col-xs-12" class="timing">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label class="col-xs-2"></label>
        <label class="col-xs-2 visible-xs"></label>
        <b>24 Hrs format<b>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <label class="col-xs-1"></label>
        <label class="col-xs-2 visible-xs"></label>
        <form class="col-xs-3" name="myTime" id="myTime">
            <uib-timepicker name="mytimee" ng-model="mytime" show-meridian="ismeridian" required></uib-timepicker>
        </form>
    </div> 
    <div class="st-head-row tdcl col-xs-12 visible-xs"></div>
</div>
```

image:
[image]

here is the ui bootstrap page: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/
the timepicker is from there

so i tried a lot of css but i did not manage to solve the problem. can someone help out with the css to keep them together??

Comment: This bootstrap does not seem valid to me. Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.
Content should be placed within columns, and only columns may be immediate children of rows.

Comment: @Matheno...please check if now its correct? but still the result is not as expected. can anyone help out with the css?